# On click of Label, nothing happens (handler is fine)

Tags: c#, winforms, click

I'm trying to create a custom interface, and to accomplish this, I have a label that on click, is supposed to close the application. The label does nothing

This happened shortly after I added a panel. I've tried moving the label to front of the panel, and changing the parent.

This is my code:

```
private void CloseLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    this.Dispose();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

The app should close. When I click, nothing happens. The handler is set up correctly!

Comment: Does it actually hit this code? does your breakpoint get triggered?

Comment: The only line that is needed is `Application.Exit()`, as Windows will automatically close the form and dispose of the memory when the application ends. As far as your question, you need to use the debugger to see if the code executes. If it doesn't, then the handler is not *set up correctly*.

Comment: "The handler is set up correctly!"  ... most likely not.

Comment: The handler is set up right, but it never hits the code. This is the handler:

     this.CloseLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CloseLabel_Click);

Comment: if your handler is set up right - you definitely will hit breakpoint on a click event. There is not _magic_ in C# WinForms, so if you not hitting your breakpoint in `CloseLabel_Click` handler - there can be **only** 2 reasons. 1: you did not set this handler. 2: you did not click your label.

Comment: Where do you have that line of code that wires up the handler?...

Comment: The designer is where I got that code (MainWindow.designer.cs)

Comment: It might be there is 2 copy/paste labels